# PHP - How to find missing dates in array of dates and fill missing gap

Tags: php-7.2, mysql-5.7

Hello great community of stackoverflow. I have a problem which i can't solve. I need to find missing dates between X number of dates. Thank you.

**Getting data from database**

```
$stmt=$db_con->prepare("SELECT date_from, date_to, country FROM work WHERE worker_id=xx");

while($row = $stmt->fetch()) { <br>
   ...
   ...
data = array("date_from" => $date_from, "date_to" => $date_to, "country" => $country);
}
```

**The data i get looks like so**
15.01.2020 --- 20.01.2020 --- Country 0
01.02.2020 --- 05.02.2020 --- Country 1
10.02.2020 --- 20.02.2020 --- Country 2

---

Those dates means when the worker start and finished with work abroad. I need to get dates to find out when worker was working in home country. The date before the first one, after last one and those in between means working in home country. My final data should be saved in array like so:

---

**01.01.2020 --- 14.01.2020 --- Home** 
15.01.2020 --- 20.01.2020 --- Country 0 
**21.01.2020 --- 31.01.2020 --- Home** 
01.02.2020 --- 05.02.2020 --- Country 1 
**6.02.2020 --- 09.02.2020 --- Home** 
10.02.2020 --- 20.02.2020 --- Country 2 
**21.02.2020 --- 31.12.2020 --- Home**

Comment: Seems simple enough, what have you to this point tried to solve the problem?

Comment: Also by the looks of your code that is not what the array looks like, please post a real var_export of the array so that we can see exactly what it looks like

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using, and also specify the version.

Comment: Do you need to store absent intervals in DB? If no it is not SQL question

Comment: @Andreas it does not seems simple to me, logic problems i guess or something. Was trying to get it work with DateTime. I create a function in php to find missing days between two dates, and than store first and last day. I planned to use this function in loop but then i got lost.

Comment: array ( 0 => array ( 'datum_od' => '01.01.2020', 'datum_do' => '10.01.2020', ), 1 => array ( 'datum_od' => '15.01.2020', 'datum_do' => '20.01.2020', ), 2 => array ( 'datum_od' => '01.02.2020', 'datum_do' => '05.02.2020', ), 3 => array ( 'datum_od' => '25.11.2019', 'datum_do' => '25.12.2019', ) --- its just a part

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev i could store array of dates into database if i would know how to get to them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the 2019 of your example is a typo since the rest of the array is sorted correctly.

Here I first make sure the first item is dated from the first of the said month. If not then it adds a "start" of the month.

Then it enters the loop and checks if there is a gap between the items and adds a home item if there is a gap.

```
$arr = array ( 0 => array ( 'datum_od' => '01.01.2020', 'datum_do' => '10.01.2020', ), 1 => array ( 'datum_od' => '15.01.2020', 'datum_do' => '20.01.2020', ), 2 => array ( 'datum_od' => '01.02.2020', 'datum_do' => '05.02.2020', ), 3 => array ( 'datum_od' => '25.11.2020', 'datum_do' => '25.12.2020', ));
$end_date = 0;

if(date('d', strtotime($arr[0]['datum_od'])) != '01'){
    $end_date = date('d.m.Y', strtotime($arr[0]['datum_od'] . ' -1 day')); 
    $new[] = array('datum_od' => date('01.m.Y', strtotime($arr[0]['datum_od'])), 'datum_do' => $end_date, 'home');
}

foreach($arr as $key => $item){
    if(date("d.m.Y", strtotime($end_date . " +1 day")) != date('d.m.Y', strtotime($item['datum_od']))){
        $end_date = date('d.m.Y', strtotime($item['datum_od'] . ' -1 day')); 
        $new[] = array('datum_od' => date('d.m.Y', strtotime($arr[$key-1]['datum_do'] . " +1 day")), 'datum_do' => $end_date, 'home');
        $new[] = $item;
    }else{
        $new[] = $item;
    }
}

var_dump($new);
```

https://3v4l.org/lCOGv

Comment: This is crazy :) Thank you so much. I would never get to this point. Was thinking in all the other directions. Can't even explain. Yes it was typo, probably i took the data from the wrong example.

Comment: @GregorŽižek great! Do you mind accepting the answer?

Comment: Andreas maybe you will know why. If i put new date in the next month (different from the previous one) and the day is number from 0-9 then i don't get home part in between. If i remove (integer) part on $end_date everything works except the date before all others acting weird.

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem, can you create an example that does this?

Comment: If the day of last date in array start with day 10 the code won't output the home part. But if day is number less than 10 say day 09 everything works perfect https://3v4l.org/dZCeG :)

Comment: Actually this only happens when the first day in dates is same https://3v4l.org/a4JWk

Comment: The if statement was wrong. I believe it's working now. See edit

Comment: Fantastic! I added a part for getting the home part after end of the array. I'm not sure if it's the best solution but it works for now. If you think it's good we can update your code. https://3v4l.org/qs7YW

Answer (score -1):

can be achieved by PHP

```
// First day of the month.
echo date('Y-m-01', strtotime($query_date));

// Last day of the month.
echo date('Y-m-t', strtotime($query_date));
```

ex:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
$first_day = date('Y-m-01', strtotime($date_from));
$before_date_from= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date_from." - 1 day"));
$last_day = date('Y-m-t', strtotime($date_from));
$after_date_to = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date_to." + 1 day"));
$data[] = array("date_from" => $first_day, "date_to" => $before_date_from, "country" => "Home");
$data[] = array("date_from" => $date_from, "date_to" => $date_to, "country" => $country);
$data[] = array("date_from" => $after_date_to, "date_to" => $last_day, "country" => "Home");
}

print_r($data); // check your result here..
```

Comment: It would be better to use DateTime class here.

Comment: Thank you i will try your solution

Comment: It start to work OK but then when it comes to next month it breaks.

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [date_from] => 01.01.2020 [date_to] => 14.01.2020 [country] => Home ) [1] => Array ( [date_from] => 15.01.2020 [date_to] => 20.01.2020 [country] => Country 0 ) [2] => Array ( [date_from] => 16.01.2020 [date_to] => 31.01.2020 [country] => Home ) [3] => Array ( [date_from] => 01.02.2020 [date_to] => 31.01.2020 [country] => Home ) [4] => Array ( [date_from] => 01.02.2020 [date_to] => 05.02.2020 [country] => Country 1 ) [5] => Array ( [date_from] => 02.02.2020 [date_to] => 29.02.2020 [country] => Home )

Comment: [6] => Array ( [date_from] => 01.02.2020 [date_to] => 09.02.2020 [country] => Home ) [7] => Array ( [date_from] => 10.02.2020 [date_to] => 20.02.2020 [country] => Country 2 ) [8] => Array ( [date_from] => 11.02.2020 [date_to] => 29.02.2020 [country] => Home ) ) array ( )

Comment: It start to work and when it comes to next month something goes wrong. [3], [5], [8] are wrong.